# Conditional expectation on a random variable versus conditional expectation on a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ taking values respectively in $\mathbb{R}^d$  and $\mathbb{R}^p$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

(1) What is the relation between $E(Y|X)$ and $E(Y|f(X))$?

(2) What is the relation between $E\Big (g(f(X))|X \Big)$ and $E\Big (g(f(X))|f(X) \Big)$?

Let $x$ denotes a realisation of $X$. I am confused by the fact that
$E(Y|X=x)$ may be different from $E(Y|f(X)=f(x))$ unless $f$ is injective. Similarly for $E\Big (g(f(X))|X=x \Big)$ and $E\Big (g(f(X))|f(X)=f(x) \Big)$.

On the other hand $\sigma(X)\supseteq \sigma(f(X))$, where $\sigma$ denotes the sigma-algebra symbol.

Could you help me to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) If $f$ is injective, then $X$ and $f(X)$ span the same $\sigma$-algebra, so $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y\mid f(X))$.

If not, you can say that $E(E(Y\mid X)\mid f(X)) = E(Y\mid f(X))$ by tower property, but practically nothing beyond that.

(2) $E(g(f(X)\mid X) = E(g(f(X)\mid f(X)) = g(f(X))$, since it is measurable with respect to $\sigma(f(X))$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding (1), is "f is injective" a sufficient and also NECESSARY condition to have $E(Y|X)=E(Y|f(X))$?

Comment: @STF, it's not necessary by all means. If, however, we require that this holds *for all* $Y$, then $f$ is necessarily injective on the support of $X$ (this is an exercise for you :) ).

Comment: Thanks for you comment on injectivity; what do you mean by "if we require that this holds for all Y"?

Comment: @STF, I mean that if $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y\mid f(X))$ *for all* integrable $Y$, then $f$ is injective on the support of $X$. Try to prove this.

Comment: Also, regarding (1) and the tower property: $E(Y|X)$ is a random function of $X$; let $E(Y|X):=m(X)$; hence $E(E(Y|X)|f(X))=E_X(m(X)|f(X))$. Can we say $E_X(m(X)|f(X))=E_X(m(X)|X)=m(X)$? I am asking this to understand whether $E(Y|f(X))=0$ can imply $E(Y|X)=0$ when $f$ is not injective. Thanks